# How do I query for tag names with :find in SnapshotStore store config

Tags: rally

I am trying to setup a filter that is similar to a defect view within a Trend chart.  The filter in the defect view is:

```
(State < Closed) AND (Severity <= Major) AND (Tags !contains Not a Stop Ship)
```

I cannot seem to get the Tags find to work correctly.  Any suggestions?

```
this.myTrendChart = Ext.create('Rally.ui.chart.Chart', {
    storeType: 'Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore',
    storeConfig: {
      find: {
        _TypeHierarchy: "Defect",
        State: {
          $lt: "Closed"
        },
        Severity: {
          $lte: "Major"
        },
        Tags: {
          $ne: "Not a Stop Ship"
        },
        _ProjectHierarchy: ProjectOid
      },
      hydrate: ["Priority"],
      fetch: ["_ValidFrom", "_ValidTo", "ObjectID", "Priority"]
    },
    calculatorType: 'My.TrendCalc',
    calculatorConfig: {},
    chartConfig: {
      chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        type: 'line'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Defects over Time'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        minTickInterval: 3
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number of Defects'
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on reviewing the JSON messages, I figured out the tag needed to be the ObjectId.  Once I found this, I replaced "Not a Stop Ship" with the ObjectId value and the filter worked correctly.